# COmo corregir este error en sql server (windows 8) x64

Tags: sql-server, windows

Trato de instalar sql server x64 en windows 8 pero me presenta los errores(adjunto imagen). ayuda por favorfracase con los primeros intentos de desintalar y volver a instalar, de cambiar de instalador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

No pude corregir el error, pero confirme que el error radica en el medio de instalcion porque revise los permisos.

Comment: ¿Ejecutaste esta herramienta con permisos de administrador?, también revisa en los enlaces que la herramienta de instalación proporciona, estos errores pueden deberse a varias causas...

Comment: dale un upgrade a Windows 8.1 y consigue todas las actualizaciones, suele ayudar :D

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que el archivo exista en el path que te dice el error, si existe verifica que estés instalando dando click derecho y ejecutar como administrador es un error de permisos en caso de que estas dos opciones no solucionen es posible que la media que estas usando para instalar este dañada y necesites bajar un nuevo ISO.